# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureClientHelper'

Tags: c#, .net, azure

When attempting to use In-Role Cache with a Azure Service (WCF Service), I recieve the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureClientHelper' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278344.aspx)

A reference must be made to the SDK DLL, even tho it is not actually utilized directly by your code. Using such things as "Optimize References" will remove it, even tho it is required and thus it will not be deployed with your Service.